# Qt:: Edit Image

Tags: qt, qlabel, qpixmap

I want to edit image in Qt application, I have use two `QLabel` and set two different image(using `QPixmap`) on each, now I wan to set one image over another(just like photo DJ set new Frame and Add Cartoons to Image).
I use drag and drop for this and I am able to move (drag) image, but this dragged image override another image. I want dragged image over second image and set position of dragged image on second image not override it.
I have added image that I want(Edit Image).
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To render the first image over the second, try something like

```
QPixmap background(":/dj.jpg");
QPixmap object(":/fish.png"); //a png with transparent background
QPixmap merge = background.copy();
QPainter painter(&merge);
painter.drawPixmap(X,Y, object); //draw the fish on background at point X,Y
painter.end();
MyLabel->setPixmap(merge); //update the label
```

Where X,Y is set with clicks or mouse-tracking.